# Add JSON object into existing JSON array using java

Tags: java, json

Here this is my JSON which I have as a string "additionalThirdParty"

```
{
    "header": null,
    "object": {
        "ASSETS": {
            "productDetails": [{
                "productId": "PT_230",
                "productThirdPartyDetails": [{
                    "thirdPartyId": "TH12",
                    "Location": "France",
                    "addtionalInfo": []
                }]
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Now my requirement is to add an extra JSON object inside "productThirdPartyDetails" array.

The new JSON object will be

```
{
    "thirdPartyId": "TH11",
    "Location": "Belgium",
    "addtionalInfo": []
}
```

So the final object should be like

```
{
    "header": null,
    "object": {
        "ASSETS": {
            "productDetails": [{
                "productId": "PT_230",
                "productThirdPartyDetails": [{
                        "thirdPartyId": "TH12",
                        "Location": "France",
                        "addtionalInfo": []
                    },
                    {
                        "thirdPartyId": "TH11",
                        "Location": "Belgium",
                        "addtionalInfo": []
                    }
                ]
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to add as follows.

converting this string to JSON as

```
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(additionalThirdParty);

    Iterator<?> keys = obj.keys();

    while (keys.hasNext()) {
        JSONObject assetsObj = obj.getJSONObject("ASSETS");
        Iterator<?> assetKeys = assetsObj.keys();
        while (assetKeys.hasNext()) {
            JSONArray productDetails = assetsObj.getJSONArray("productDetails");
            logger.info("productDetails=" + productDetails);
        }
    }
```

It throws me that  org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["ASSETS"] not found.

Any ideas on how to add a new object into that array

Comment: **Assets** object lies inside **object** so in order to get **Assets**, you have to first get **object** JSONObject.

Comment: the `productDetails` array have only one element? or you want to add the new element for the productId `"productId": "PT_230"`

Comment: @ajc, product will be one, but it will have multiple third parties.

Comment: Ok, so you just need to focus on understanding how to iterate over a JSONObject. Understand difference between JSONObject, JSONArray and how to read keys and values. Nishesh's answer covers it.

Comment: @ajc, definetely I will try Nishesh solution and update tomorrow morning as Im at home now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve what you want, you have to properly reach out to **productThirdPartyDetails** as shown below, then you have to identify the way of getting JSONObject that needs to be added, I have hardcoded that part it's better to get that object through a method.

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(additionalThirdParty);


        JSONObject objtobeadded =  new JSONObject();
        objtobeadded.put("thirdPartyId", "TH11");
        objtobeadded.put("Location", "Belgium");
        objtobeadded.put("addtionalInfo", new JSONArray());

        JSONObject assetsObj = obj.getJSONObject("object").getJSONObject("ASSETS");

        JSONArray prodDetailsArr = assetsObj.getJSONArray("productDetails");

        for(int i=0;i<prodDetailsArr.length();i++){            
            JSONArray arr = prodDetailsArr.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("productThirdPartyDetails");
            arr.put(objtobeadded);
        }
        System.out.println(obj.toString());
```

Comment: Nishesh, let me check and get back to u

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONObject assetsObj = obj.getJSONObject("ASSETS"); here the ASSETS is in under object,
```

So you should write `obj.getJSONObject("object").getJSONObject("ASSETS");` to get the ASSETS object.